# how to calculate the amount of mass ejected from a stellar system?

Tags: stellar-physics

I need to write a python program to find the amount of mass ejected from a stellar system and how much is retained. for this I need to calculate the quantity

$$\int \rho (\vec {r}) f (\vec {v} (\vec {r})) d^3r$$

where f is a function = 0 if the velocity locally exceeds the escape velocity, as determined by the local value of the gravitational potential, and f = 1 otherwise.

Can you suggest me a flowchart where to start from? 
I think I need to start defining the total energy of the system and then checking if the velocity is less than escape velocity. But I still need some guided tour to set the arguments.
thanks

Comment: Where do $\rho(\vec r)$ and $v(\vec r)$ come from? Are you being asked to evaluate the numerical integral of a known function in Python or is your professor expecting you to write a hydrodynamic simulation without previous knowledge in programming? If it's the latter, then you are in a world of hurt, so I assume it's the former?

Comment: I assume it's the later. I already have the files with known gravitational potential and other known quantities in yt. but I am completely new to any sort of programming, so I need to set up the arguments(like what would be expression for total energy in this system, how to set up the if..else argument to determine ejected mass etc) to evaluate the integral. I can extract programming help from yt and python community.

Comment: In that case a (naive) implementation of a three dimensional integral are three nested loops and your largest problem may be to read the content of those files by the program. How that parser code has to look like depends entirely on the file structure (binary, ascii, data base files?) and it can range from roughly three lines to pages after pages of code. You also have to consider the size of the data set. If you can load the entire data into memory, the program will be more straight forward than one that has to go trough billions of data points. The answer is therefor: it depends...